# JS or Jquery generic way to change class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, class, button

I get the following case:

**Elements:** Image A, Image B, Button A, Button B

**Default:**
 
1. Show Image A and hide Image B.(add class name "hidden")
2. Style added to activated Button A.(add class name "active")

**Function:**
1. Show Image A and hide Image B when clicking Button A. And vice versa.
2. Style is added to the activated button. And vice versa.

**Code:**

```
<img class="image" src="ImageA.jpg" />
<img class="image hidden" src="ImageB.jpg" />
<div class="Button active">Button A</div>
<div class="Button">Button B</div>
```

I want to apply the function to more than one of the above case without making further change of JavaScript. Is there any method to present the JS in a generic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img id="imageA" class="image" src="ImageA.jpg" />
<img id="imageB" class="image hidden" src="ImageB.jpg" />
<button attr-image="imageA" class="Button active">Button A</button>
<button attr-image="imageB" class="Button">Button B</button>

$(".button").click(function(){
    $('.image').addClass('hidden');
    $('#'+$(this).attr('attr-image')).removeClass('hidden');
    $('.button').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

What it does is with each button it stores the id of corresponding image..

when a button is clicked, it adds `hidden` to all images, and then removes it from the one corresponding to the button..

Same way for button first remove all buttons `active` class, and then add to the one clicked..

Comment: Thank you Rajat. But I still get the following problems:1. The 2 div are not click-able.2. The JS seem cannot be run even the html linked to jquery.js. Please help.

Comment: The 2 div are not click-able. So I added <a class="Button" href="javascript:;"></a> inside the div. But the JS seem then cannot be run even the html is linked to jquery.js. Please advice.

Comment: I know what's wrong, I get a wrong button ID (should be "button" but not "Button"). The function works perfectly now. Thank you so much for your help, Rajat.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need 2 divs and 2 buttons, if you want to switch an image. You could switch the image `src` within one image, using one button. Something like:

HTML:

```
<img id="switchme" data-checked="0" class="image" src="imageA.png" />
<div id="switch" class="Button">Button A</div>
```

Script (JQuery):

```
​$('#switch').on('click',
 function​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​(){
  var img = $('#switchme') 
     ,ischecked = Boolean(+img.attr('data-checked'))
     ,src = ischecked
            ? 'imageA.png'
            : 'imageB.png'
  ;
  img.attr({'src':src, 'data-checked': +(!ischecked)});
});
```

See [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tdrjs/) (also contains an alternative using css class for switching, and a '2 button/1 image'-solution)

Comment: Thank you Kooilnc. In fact I really need 2 buttons for user to identify their choice. But your suggestion of only having 1 image stated is quite inspirited. This technique must be useful for me in any day of the future.

Comment: Glad I could inspire you. Just for fun: for a '2 button/1 image'-solution, see http://jsfiddle.net/pAhuK/